# How to show all DB result with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, echo

So,
I just started with PDO and the connection and stuff work great, but now I have a little problem. I'm stuck on a part where I want to show 6 results per table.   My code is as following:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 6";
$stmt->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
$stmt->bindParam(':hours', $hours);
try {
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $result = $stmt->execute($parameters);
} while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
   <tr>
       <td><b><?php echo $row['hours'] ?></b></td>
       <td><a href="#"></a></td>
       <td id="dayhour-1">
           <input placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="1" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>">
       </td>
   </tr>
<?php  } $stmt->close(); ?>
```

DB connecting:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "xxx";
$db_user = "xxx";
$db_pass = "xxx";
$db_opts = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);
$conn    = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8mb4", $db_user, $db_pass, $db_opts);
?>
```

When I go to the webpage, it is showing the well-known 500 error. I have no idea what I am doing wrong because I am a starter.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this problem.

---

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 6"; 

$stmt->bindParam(':userName', $userName); 
$stmt->bindParam(':hours', $hours); 

try { 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($stmt); 
} catch ($row = $result->fetch() { 

?> 

<tr>
    <td><b><?php echo $row['hours'] ?></b></td>
    <td><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td id="dayhour-1">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>">
    </td>
</tr> 

<?php } $stmt->close(); ?>
```

Comment: you didn't include the binds in values.

Comment: you're also mixing different mysql apis and Lord only knows which one is used to connect with

Comment: Looking at your server's error logs always helps in debugging. The error message is there.

Comment: Your code failed on too many levels.

Comment: Well, I tried hahah @Fred-ii-

Comment: stick with the one api, PDO. You used `fetch_assoc()` which is mysqli_, not PDO and what I said earlier about the not using the named placeholders in values

Comment: 5XX errors are caused by server. even though you have some mistakes in your code & it won't work even in a well configured server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

```
<?php
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5";
                            $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b><?php echo $row->hours ?></b></td>
                                    <td><a href="#"></a></td>
                                    <td id="dayhour-1">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1" value="<?php echo $row->username ?>">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
```

This code will do it's work. Its completely perfect PDO and it works 100%. A friend helped my out.

Comment: Good to hear you got a solution!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so i can see an error here to start with:

- `try() {} while() {}` is not going to work.

This is combining syntax from `do {} while()` and `try {} catch() {}`. This will be throwing a 500 internal server error.

Secondly, as per the comments, you will want to standardize on one database connector. I would probably go with `PDO`.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

---

**EDIT**

Here is an example of a prepared statement using `PDO`

```
<?php

// Connect to your database
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database", "username", "password")
        ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare your statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM db WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?");

// Execute the statement
$results = $stmt->execute([1,6])->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Loop through your resuls
foreach ($results as $row) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo $row['hours'] ?></b></td>
            <td><a href="#"></a></td>
            <td id="dayhour-1">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Well, @Spholt ,  I tried the following but wont work:
`<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 6";
$stmt->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
$stmt->bindParam(':hours', $hours);
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute($stmt);
} catch ($row = $result->fetch(){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><b><?php echo $row['hours'] ?></b></td>
        <td><a href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="dayhour-1">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php  } $stmt->close(); ?>`
What I am doing wrong

Comment: Please don't just say "It won't work".... please give the EXACT error message that you get. Imagine yourself in the position of a support person trying to help someone who only says "It doesn't work...." :-)

Comment: @Willem-Jelle I have taken you code and it still looks like you have basic syntax errors. I would recommend using a text editor or IDE with a linter to highlight these problems.

Comment: I did not give your reaction a dislike :o. BTW if I put in your code, I dont get a page error (5** error), but the information won't show up too. Thanks for the efford, really appreciate it bro @Spholt

Comment: hmm, have you tried turning on error reporting at the top of your script? `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It will give us a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @Spholt: please don't add voting commentary to posts. It's fine to add it into comments, though I don't think it has any effect!

Comment: @halfer Fair point. I'm just getting a little fed up with answering questions and either getting no credit or getting random down votes :(

Comment: Hmm, it is not clear why people have voted that way. Sometimes if a question quality is very poor (e.g. unresearched) then people downvote answers on the basis that lazy question askers should not be helped. However that does not seem to be the case here. Your answer seems OK to me; it has an XSS vulnerability, but that comes from the question.

Comment: @Spholt I already tried to do do it with the php errors, but it gave me the same reaction. Error 500..

Comment: @Spholt OMG! I have the solution. Will Place it myself.