# Update Variables in database via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So, I've been practicing with PDO, see my [earlier asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700798/how-to-show-all-db-result-with-pdo) and now I am stuck at the following point:

I want to update the database variables without pushing on a button, and in my opinion is it best doable via AJAX.

---

A few codes:
General.JS

```
var timeoutId;
$('form input').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    console.log('Invoer bewerking');

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change
        saveToDB();
    }, 1000);
});

function saveToDB()
{
    console.log('Opslaan naar Database');
    form = $('.formulier24');
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            $('.HowAbout').html('Opslaan...');
        },
        success: function(data) { console.error(data) ;
            var jqObj = jQuery(data); // You can get data returned from your ajax call here. ex. jqObj.find('.returned-data').html()
            // Now show them we saved and when we did
            var d = new Date();
            $('.HowAbout').html('Opgeslagen om: ' + d.toLocaleTimeString());
        },
    });
}

// This is just so we don't go anywhere
// and still save if you submit the form
$('.formulier24').submit(function(e) {
    saveToDB();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

ajax.php FILE:

```
<?php
include('verbinding.php');
if(isset($_POST['formulier24'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE INTO evenement SET username = :username, hours = :hours";
    $parameters = array($_POST["username"], $_POST["hours"]);
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':hours', $_POST['hours']);
        $result = $stmt->execute($parameters);
        $return = "Updated data successfully!";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $return = "Could not update data! Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

The connection file (verbinding.php) is 100% working. I think I made a fault in the ajax.php file but I dont know where. Please let me know what I did wrong, because I do not get the **Saved at time date**-mention and it does not save in the database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem? You didn't say the error

Comment: yes what is the error? and for the "improving code" portion of question, you should go to different stack exchange site, i think "code review"

Comment: My bad. Updated! ^^

Comment: Do you have any PHP errors?

Comment: @BjörnC Nope. I dont get any

Comment: Your update syntax might be the problem, supposed to be : Update tableName Set columnName =value where columnane = value

Comment: Echo out the $sql that is generated by the pdo, to make sure it is what you expect. $stmt->queryString.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried, but without succes. Thanks for thinking with me tho.

Comment: @Andrew Thats this part right: `$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);`

Comment: oh right that doesn't exist, you need to add your own function to pull the paramaterized query. EG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements In any case, your query looks ok, but most likelu your POSTed variables are invalid/ the name's in the form are incorrect, do var_dump($_POST) at the top to see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code seems to be expecting a POST variable that represents the form, but that's not what [jQuery serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) produces. It produces a POST string containing the names of all the (successful) controls and their values, so PHP will receive a POST parameter per control.

**EDIT:** To clarify, what I mean is that your `isset` check on `$_POST['formulier24']` will always return false if formulier24 is the name of the form.

Comment: But what do I have to put over there in stead of `$_POST['formulier24']`. Also, when I put there something else than the **Saved at time/date** won't show up.

Comment: I can't write your code for you. Start by looking at what you're actually sending as POST variables, e.g. by doing a `console.log` of `form.serialize()`, so that you understand what you're sending and what the PHP script can work with.